# Freebase PHP Google API (google-api-php-client)

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm using the google-api-php-client (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
When I try to connect to the Freebase service I get the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Google_Service_Freebase::call()
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
$freebase->search(array('automotive');
```

The search function in the Freebase service looks like this:

```
public function search($optParams = array())
{
  $params = array();
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  return $this->call('search', array($params));
}
```

It calls to an internal function call, but it doesn't exists in the class..

Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the lib code (which is in beta and changed a lot since the last version), I think that return line should be:

```
return $this->base_methods->call('search', array($params));
```

I can't try this now, but if you do and it work, you could submit a bug report on their Github (I saw your post there :).